# Get file extension in OS X using Java

Tags: java, macos, file

I want to get the file extension in my Java code:

```
File f = new File(....);
String name = f.getName();
int pos = name.lastIndexOf('.');
String ext = name.substring(pos+1);
```

I tried this code but it didn't work in OS X Lion, in Windows it works.

**UPDATE**
for example 
i have a png file in my desktop with this name `Screen Shot 2012-02-23 at 1.26.27 PM`
i get the `27 PM` extension with this code .

Comment: What's the error you are getting in **OS X**?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What's the resulting value of `ext`? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: What's the problem with it? What input did you give it that doesn't work and what did it give you back?

Comment: you're dropping the file extension somewhere else... it works perfect.. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing exactly what you've asked it to do. It's finding the **filename** extension on the file. The problem is that you have file with a stupid name that *should* have a ".png" extension, but doesn't. If you still want your code to handle this, you might need to look at interpreting the file header to determine the **type** of the file, which is presumably what OS X is doing to know that it is really a .png file.

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX not all files have extension, probably that's what is happening with you, but until you provide an stacktrace or a more clear definition of *didn't work*  I can't tell.

I took your code and create a sample:

```
localhost:Desktop oscarryz$ cat Fe.java 
import java.io.File;
import static java.lang.System.out;

class Fe {
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        File f = new File("Screen Shot 2012-03-06 at 10.03.35 PM.png");
        out.println("File exists: " + f.exists() );
        out.println("Extension: "   + 
            f.getName().substring( f.getName().lastIndexOf('.')+1) 
        );
    }
}
localhost:Desktop oscarryz$ javac Fe.java 
localhost:Desktop oscarryz$ java Fe 
File exists: true
Extension: png
```

You are probably dropping the extension when passing the file name, because the mechanism you show does works on OSX perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

What output you are getting i have OSX SnowLeopard on that this is working fine please keep in mind file separator you need to be select as per operating system. that can be a problem as you haven't shown file name i can suggest this only please **check file separator**.

Solution is from garsinfotech.com labs

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [FilenameUtils#getExtension()](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html).